# how to make crystal reports find database on client pc

Tags: c#, sql, crystal-reports

my C# application uses Crystal Report and its work fine , But when my application work on client every thing work except Crystal Report ,its said crystal Report Could Not find database path!!!
I all ready installed Crystal Report run-time package.

Comment: What is your database connection string in Crystal Reports?

Comment: SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=ComplainsDb;Integrated Security=True");

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Data source .\SQLEXPRESS is looking for the database on your local (.) machine.  If you change this to use the machine name it will work, for example

```
Data Source=Servername\SQLEXPRESS
```

Comment: my application have several report all work fine except one give me error "Database Error Vendor 17 Can Not Access Database!!"

Comment: What is connection string for that report? The same as the others? Is there any second connection in that report?

Comment: I have never heard of that error.  There must be something different about that report.  Does it run from the same server as the others, or a different server?  Does it have subreports that maybe have their own connection strings?  Something must be different, right?

Answer (score 0):

I delete the report that doesn't work (manually created) and then create a new one by using crystal report wizard , that solve the problem!